# Создание динамического прыжка в unity 2d

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

во всех туториалах в ютубе для проверки касания с землёй используется новый круглый объект, но он не идеально по форме подходит к моему персонажу, что делать (у моего персонажа polygon collider 2d). Спасибо

Comment: Что не так работает? Какой круглый объект? Сделайте Box Collider2d для земли.

Comment: Во всех туториалах, для проверки касания с землёй создаётся триггер округлой формы, и с помощью Physics2d.OverlapCircle, проверяется касание этого триггер с землёй, но круг не подходит моему персонажу, и получается что когда персонаж ещё до конца не упал, уже срабатывает триггер и персонаж может снова прыгать даже не коснувшись с землёй

Comment: Какой-то очень странный способ описали. Сделайте box collider2d для земли и получайте столкновения через OnCollisionEnter2D

Answer (score 1):

в компонентах полигон коллайдера есть компонент istrigger, и этот компонент отвечает для проверки касаний.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, но можно чуть-чуть по подробнее, вы знаете какие нибудь туториалы на эту тему, или скиньте код с примеры. Спасибо

Comment: https://youtu.be/GVQ8rDbpuL4

Comment: Этот метод мне не подходит, работает не очень, при малейшем отрыве от земли перестаёт работать, нужно использовать что-то связанное с Phisycs2D или  RaycastHit2D